# How to obtain both obtain closed formula for the Cantor set?

Tags: recursion, cantor-set

This one is related to the Cantor set, more explicitly, how to obtain a closed formula for the Cantor set?

$$ \mathcal{C} = \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} \bigcap_{k=0}^{3^{n-1}-1} \left(\left[0\,,\, \frac{3k+1}{3^n}\right] \cup \left[\frac{3k+2}{3^n}\,,\,1\right] \right)$$

Equivalently, this set can also be represented as:

$$ \mathcal{C} = [0,1] \setminus \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} \bigcup_{k=0}^{3^{n-1}-1} \left( \frac{3k+1}{3^n} ,\frac{3k+2}{3^n}\right)$$

How do you obtain both of these formulation?

Both these formulations are mentioned in the [wikipage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set) of cantor set.

Comment: As far as I have learned, that is the very definition of Cantor set... what do you mean by *how to obtain*?

Comment: I don't trust the top formula from wiki. The inner intersection is only expressing the left most (at k=0) and right most (at k=3^(n-1)-1) pieces of the Cantor set at stage n. When taken to infinity, shouldn't the top formula converge to just the two points {0,1}?

Comment: When $n=2$, for example, then inner intersection gives [0,1/9] U [2/9, 4/9] U [5/9,7/9] U [8/9, 1] (check it carefully). But the outer intersection already eliminated (1/3, 2/3), so after n=1 and n=2 you have [0,1/9] U [2/9,3/9] U [6/9,7/9] U [8/9,1], as desired.